# How do I Monkey-patch a gem with a hierarchy?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, thor

I'm trying to add a new method to the Thor gem.  Specifically, I want to add a method to Thor::Shell::Basic.  In my gem based on thor, in bin/mycommand, I have this:

```
require 'thor'
require 'ext/thor/extension'
Thor.include ThorExtensions::Thor::Shell::Basic
MyCommand.start
```

In lib/ext/thor/extension.rb, I have:

```
module ThorExtensions
  module Thor
    module Shell
      module Basic
        def extension_method
```

When I call extension_method, I get an error that says it can't read an attribute of Thor::Shell::Basic (padding, specifically).  When I go into Thor::Shell::Basic, in pry, I see my method listed as a method of that class, but it doesn't seem to be able to access it at runtime.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reopen classes in ruby:

```
class Thor::Shell::Basic
  def extension_method
  end
end
```

Or you can inlcude your extension(s) as a module (I prefer this one):

```
module MyExtension
  def extension_method
  end
end

Thor::Shell::Basic.send :include, MyExtension
```

Comment: In the latter case, would I include that last line in the bin/mycommand file that starts a thor run, or would I include it in the same file as module MyExtension and then require that file in my gem? I keep trying different methods of including my code, which works fine when I manually do it in pry, but either doesn't get included at all when I run bin/mycommand or the method exists, but can't access the private methods of Thor::Shell::Basic.

Comment: It doesn't matter where it is as long it's added before `MyCommand.start`.

Comment: Yes and no...  it worked, but after digging deeper, I realized that there were deeper problems due to the way Thor is written. I was able to patch Thor::Shell::Basic, but I believe because Thor::Shell autoloads Thor::Shell::Basic, it was overwriting my patch.  As a result, I ended up just writing a separate function in my own code rather than patching Thor.